# How to enter data to excel sheet through web form

Tags: php, html, excel

I am trying to create webform and storing submitted data in excel sheet
below is the HTML code saved as"update1.html"

```
<form action=xcel.php method="post">
<p>
<lable>ENTER SAMPLE NAME</lable>
<input type="text"  name="so">

<p>
<lable>ENTER STATUS</lable>
<input type="text"  name="status">
</p>

<p><button>UPDATE</button></p>
</form>
```

and PHP script as "xcel.php"

```
  <?php

 $SO_ID=$_POST['so'];
 $Status=$_POST['status'];

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("asheet.xlsx");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $SO_ID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', $Status);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("asheet.xlsx");
```

and in excel sheet i.e "asheet.xlsx" 2 column are there "so" and "status".
I need to take user input from web form and store that in the excel sheet like how we store data in database.
i am not getting proper formatted data in excel sheet.
[image: THIS IS THE OUTPUT I AM GETTING] 
any further information feel free to ask
thanks in advance

Comment: you can't open a **.xlsx** like a text file ... use phpexcel() or something else

Comment: where i have to add phpexcel() in my script??

Comment: If you have to try writing a csv file, use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function; but as MS Excel reads csv files using a locale-specific separator, some copies of MS Excel will work with a comma (`,`), others might require a semi-colon (`;`)

Comment: If you want to use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to generate a real xlsx file, then download it and read the documentation

Comment: i am not getting how to change this php script to phpexcel format, can u help me out plz

Comment: Mark already helped you - download and read

Comment: see my updated php script, than also its not working, same output

Comment: Simply including a lbrary doesn't magically change what you were already doing.

Comment: that only i am soo much confused about how to edit!!! if possible plz help me out in scripting

Comment: Looking at the documentation and some of the examples, like `01simple.php` should show you how to do it

Answer (score 2):

OK, spoon-feeding time

EITHER

```
<?php

$SO_ID=$_POST['so'];
$Status=$_POST['status'];

$fp=fopen("/var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx","w");
fputcsv($fp, array($SO_ID, $Status), ';'); 
fclose($fp);

echo"thanks";
```

to write a csv file with a `;` delimiter, and pretend that it's an Excel file

OR

```
<?php

$SO_ID=$_POST['so'];
$Status=$_POST['status'];

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $SO_ID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', $Status);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("/var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx");
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: so in /var/www/html/apps/xcel.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: status in /var/www/html/apps/xcel.php on line 4

Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx): Permission denied in /var/www/html/apps/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 236

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file /var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx.' in /var/www/html/apps/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:399 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/apps/xcel.php(13): 

These are the erros i am getting sir

Comment: Then do some basic debugging..... if you're getting `Undefined index: so` then your web form isn't sending that to the xcel.php script

Comment: If you're getting an error `Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx): Permission denied` then make sure that the file isn't open (if it already exists) or that your web script has permission to write to that file/folder

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file asheet.xlsx.' in /var/www/html/apps/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:399 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/apps/xcel.php(13): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('asheet.xlsx') #1 /var/www/html/apps/error.php(4): include('/var/www/html/a...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/apps/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 399

Comment: this is the error i am gettin sir, how to fix this??

Comment: If you're getting an error `Warning: unlink(/var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx): Permission denied` then make sure that the file isn't open (if it already exists) or that your web script has permission to write to that file/folder

Comment: no its not opened and i setted chmod 777 permossion also

Comment: Does that permission apply all the way up through the folders? eg. what permission does `/var` have? what permission does `/var/www` have? what permission does `/var/www/html` have?

Comment: i setted same permission for the whole path than also 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file asheet.xlsx.' in /var/www/html/apps/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:399 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/apps/xcel.php(13): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('asheet.xlsx') #1 /var/www/html/apps/error.php(4): include('/var/www/html/a...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/apps/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 399

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82596/discussion-between-aditya-k-and-mark-baker).